# In AwesomeWM, is the use of `c:kill()` as soft as clicking on the red cross in another window manager?

Tags: window-manager, kill, awesome

In AwesomeWM, windows are closed with the method `c:kill()`
(bound to <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>)

When I use that key binding, the window just close instantly!

Therefore I wondered :

- Is that way as soft as clicking on the red cross in another window manager? (such as openbox)
- Is there a softer way to close a window? (from the window-manager side)